# Jquery remove class and add class on clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with 6 p's in it. And I start with the first p having the class "active" now when you press an other p I want that active class to be removed and added on the clicked p

This is what I have the class is being added on the clicked p but not being removed from the other p's.

This is my html:

```
<div class="slider-circles">
   <p id="slide1" class="transparent-circle active"></p>
   <p id="slide2" class="transparent-circle"></p>
   <p id="slide3" class="transparent-circle"></p>
   <p id="slide4" class="transparent-circle"></p>
   <p id="slide5" class="transparent-circle"></p>
   <p id="slide6" class="transparent-circle"></p>
```

This is my jquery

```
$(".slider-circles p").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if($(this).hasClass("active")){
                $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("active");
            }
            $(this).addClass("active"); 
});
```

Comment: add to click event $('.transparent-circle.active').removeClass('active');

Answer (score 2):

Try to grab the closest `.slider-circles` and find children elements with class `.active` and remove that class. After that just add class `active` to the current element.

```
$(".slider-circles p").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $(".active", $(this).closest(".slider-circles")).removeClass("active");
 $(this).addClass("active"); 
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1mhg0zvv/)

Answer (score 2):

Since the `p` are siblings already you should not call the `.parent()`.

```
$(".slider-circles p").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
      $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need a one liner:

```
$(".slider-circles p").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic will be like this -

1. On click on `p` tag
2. You will remove `active` class from all `p` tags
3. You will add class to that `p` tag

So, in this way, you will always have clean and short code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slider-circles p').click(function() {
    $('.slider-circles p').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: steelblue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-circles">
  <p id="slide1" class="transparent-circle active">1 Para</p>
  <p id="slide2" class="transparent-circle">2 Para</p>
  <p id="slide3" class="transparent-circle">3 Para</p>
  <p id="slide4" class="transparent-circle">4 Para</p>
  <p id="slide5" class="transparent-circle">5 Para</p>
  <p id="slide6" class="transparent-circle">6 Para</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.active').removeClass('active');` or `$('p.active').removeClass('active');` is also can be used.

Comment: I find this is very clean way, without involving too many classes! :)